# is there any solution for below error in my smart contract

Tags: solidity

I am working on a Solidity smart contract that I successfully deployed. However, I am getting an error when calling the staking function. The debug output shows the error occurs on this line of code:

token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount)

the transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
note: the called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. debug the transaction to get more information.

here is my code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import {ERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/math/SafeMath.sol";
/**
 * @title stakingcontract
 * @dev coin staking 
 * @custom:dev-run-script ./scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts
 */

contract stakingcontract {
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    ERC20 public token;
    uint256 public rewardRate; 
    uint256 public stakingDuration; 
    
    mapping(address => uint256) public stakes;
    mapping(address => uint256) public lastUpdateTime;
    mapping(address => uint256) public rewards;

    event Staked(address indexed user, uint256 amount);
    event Withdrawn(address indexed user, uint256 amount);
    event RewardPaid(address indexed user, uint256 reward);

    constructor(ERC20 _token) {
        token = _token;
        rewardRate = 2 ether; // 2% in wei
        stakingDuration = 10 minutes;
    }
    receive() external payable {}
    
    modifier updateReward(address account) {
        rewards[account] = earned(account);
        lastUpdateTime[account] = block.timestamp;
        _;
    }

    
    function earned(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 elapsedTime = block.timestamp.sub(lastUpdateTime[account]);
        return stakes[account].mul(rewardRate).mul(elapsedTime).div(1e20);
    }

    
    function staking(uint256 amount) updateReward(msg.sender) external  payable {
        require(amount > 0, "Cannot stake 0");
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        stakes[msg.sender] = stakes[msg.sender].add(amount);
        emit Staked(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    
    function withdraw() public updateReward(msg.sender) {
        uint256 amount = stakes[msg.sender];
        require(amount > 0, "Cannot withdraw 0");
        stakes[msg.sender] = 0;
        uint256 reward = rewards[msg.sender];
        if (reward > 0) {
            rewards[msg.sender] = 0;
            require(token.transfer(msg.sender, amount.add(reward)), "Token transfer failed");
            emit RewardPaid(msg.sender, reward);
        } else {
            require(token.transfer(msg.sender, amount), "Token transfer failed");
        }
        emit Withdrawn(msg.sender, amount);
    }

   
    function exit() external {
        withdraw();
    }
}
```